# Redirect user based on province (in Canada)

Tags: redirect, geolocation, location

I've done some digging around, but my complete lack of any experience with geolocation or IP location based services has made it very difficult for me to find the best, simplest, and most cost effective solution to my problem.

I have a website that asks it's visitors which province they're from (on the homepage, and in the header/footer for easy accessibility on any page of the site). We offer four provinces to choose from, (BC, AB, SK, ONT). I would like to redirect visitors to their appropriate province when they try to visit the homepage so that they can avoid this first step entirely.

If the visitor isn't from any of these provinces they would just be sent to the homepage.

Hopefully this isn't too difficult to acheive. Any direction is great

Comment: geolocation, and/or long-term cookie.

Comment: Just curious. You don't expect visitior from other provinces like Manitoba ?  I could understand that you don't expect visitor coming From Québec and atlantic provinces.

Comment: I'm sure we'll get visitors from all around Canada and maybe the odd visitors from around the rest of the world as well. These visitors just wouldn't trigger any redirection.